# captions: combining justification=centering with format=hang?

Tags: captions

is it possible to combine `justification=centering` with `format=hang`?
In standard mode, the caption package sets multiline captions as `justification=raggedright`.  I would like to have all captions centered. Yet, when i use `justification=centering`, every single line is centered by itself, not the caption as one entity.
Please see my MWE. Basically, i want the caption as is but centered.
Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(3,0.5) circle [radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption\\
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.1pt}\\
\scriptsize Dashed helplines apply to total sample.}
\label{fig:sex} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `justification=justified`?

Comment: Also, please make your code an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (with emphasis on _minimal_). I think your questiion could easily be illustrated within a dozen short lines of code.

Comment: It seems as if you want to add something like a "footnote"  through the `caption` command. Probably you can remove the line and move "Dashed helplines apply to total sample."  next to the legend of the plot?

Comment: You might also take a look at the `boxhandler` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stack the caption elements, rather than using the `hang` format.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(3,0.5) circle [radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[A caption]{\Longunderstack[l]{A caption\\
\rule{.35\textwidth}{.1pt}\\
\scriptsize Dashed helplines apply to total sample.}}
\label{fig:sex} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`\\` fills the rest of the line up with empty space. Your caption is actually centered, you just have a whole lot of empty space in your caption. If you don't want the full width, you can tell LaTeX so using a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[font=normalsize,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\foo

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(3,0.5) circle [radius=3];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{A caption that may well be too long for one line, in which case line breaks are needed.
    \vskip 1ex\hrule\vskip 1ex
    \scriptsize Dashed helplines apply to total sample.
  }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]